# PHP Array_merge involving $_SESSION doesn't work

Tags: php, array-merge

This code doesn't seem to work:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['filtros_web_jobs'] = array();
array_merge( $_SESSION['filtros_web_jobs'], $_POST['filtros_web_form'] );
var_dump($_SESSION);
var_dump($_POST);
session_write_close();
exit;
```

Outputs:

```
array(1) {
  ["filtros_web_jobs"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
array(1) {
  ["filtros_web_form"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["cola"]=>
    string(18) "fisica_Renova_zxcv"
  }
}
```

Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: Because $_SESSION['filtros_web_jobs'] might have other values that I am not putting here so the code remains clean.

Comment: correct usage of array_merge would help `$x=array_merge($y, $z);` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) returns an array. It does not mutate the arrays that are passed to it.

```
$merged = array_merge( $_SESSION['filtros_web_jobs'], $_POST['filtros_web_form'] );
```

Answer (score 2):

From [Array merge on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

> Return Values
>
> Returns the resulting array.

You aren't setting the output to anything - Try this:

```
$output = array_merge( $_SESSION['filtros_web_jobs'], $_POST['filtros_web_form'] );
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

array_merge returns the new, merged array.
Try:

```
$a = array_merge( $_SESSION['filtros_web_jobs'], $_POST['filtros_web_form'] );
var_dump($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not cached the data that array_merge function is giving you after merging the arrays.

```
 $mergedArray = array_merge( $_SESSION['filtros_web_jobs'], $_POST['filtros_web_form'] );
```